# Beamer: Adding a text in arbitrary position in a frame with background image

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to set a frame with a background image and some text over the image in some arbitrary position.

My last attempt was something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
{
  \usebackgroundtemplate {
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.center)}]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=1.2\paperwidth]{imgs/background.jpg}};
    \node [xshift=2cm, yshift=-4cm] (anchorA)  at (0,0)  {TEST TEXT};
  }
  
  \begin{frame}
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that if you use `\tikz ...` without `{...}` around the content, then it will only act on the first node. The second node is not part of it. At the very minimum you could add `{...}` around the content of the macro.

---

However if you have more than one node in an image, I usually find it easier to use a `tikzpicture` environment instead of `\tikz`.

I also suggest to use this little trick from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989 to get coordinates relative to the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    }
}

\begin{document}
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \node at (0.5,0.5) {\includegraphics[width=1.2\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}};
    \node at (0.7,0.1)  {TEST TEXT};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  
  \begin{frame}
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]